# Skew blog images without affecting them in WordPress using divi

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Does anyone know how to achieve this (the blog images) in WordPress using divi theme
[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoMoK.png)

thanks

Answer (score -1):

I Don't know a lot about code, however perhaps a good work around, would be Photoshop. As long as the webpage background matches the edge of the images, it could work